# JsTestDriver - $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, js-test-driver

I'm getting a strange problem, claiming that $ is not a function/is undefined. Obviously, this means that it thinks JQuery isn't defined, but if I view the source of the page and check requests, JQuery is definitely being pulled.

```
Total 0 tests (Passed: 0; Fails: 0; Errors: 0) (0.00 ms)
  Firefox 8.0 Linux: Run 10 tests (Passed: 0; Fails: 0; Errors 10) (0.00 ms)
    error loading file: /test/src/coffee.js:88: $ is not a function
```

My config file is as follows;

```
server: http://localhost:9876
timeout: 90
load:
    - src/datejs.js
    - src/jquery-1.6.4.js
    - src/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
    - src/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js
    - src/jquery.jgrowl.js
    - src/jquery.qtip.js
    - src/typewatch.js
    - src/tristate.js
    - src/jquery.weekcalendar.js
    - src/highcharts.js
    - src/coffee.js
    - # rest omitted for brevity...
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I've tried removing my JQuery entries in case they're overlapping with the ones in the version provided by JsTestDriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've sometimes run across issues using '$' (particularly in Drupal). Does replacing '$' with 'jQuery' have any effect?

Comment: I've done the next best thing, and done `$ = jQuery` which has worked. So I'm marking your answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to call jquery-1.6.4.js before datejs.js. then instead of $ user jQuery.

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: Why? I don't think datejs.js uses jQuery.

Comment: i don't have code may be it use it is better to call jquery first. if datejs uses jquery then we must hvae to call jquery first.

Comment: Datejs.js definitely doesn't use jQuery :)